# What are the special medications to treat Covid-19?

Tags: medications, covid-19, treatment, treatment-options, symptoms

We know there is no cure for Covid-19 (currently) and the
treatment focuses on managing symptoms as the virus runs its course.

The main [symptoms of Covid-19](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/symptoms-testing/symptoms.html) are

-Fever

-Cough

-Shortness of breath

There's no need to seek medical attention unless

-Trouble breathing

-Persistent pain or pressure in the chest

-New confusion or inability to arouse

-Bluish lips or face

---

From [healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/coronavirus-covid-19#treatment) the examples of therapies used for these illnesses include:

- antiviral or retroviral medications
- breathing support, such as mechanical ventilation
- steroids to reduce lung swelling
- blood plasma transfusions

But there's no mention of specific medications.

I have checked other pages and again, no specific medications.

I know there is a lot of medication of antivirals, to treat cough, fever, etc.

But is a special medication to treat these symptoms that came particularly from Covid-19 infection?

Or it doesn't matter that the symptoms came from Covid-19? they could be treated as a common cough or common fever, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

There are no specific proven drug treatments for Covid-19 disease but quite a few claims based on very limited experience which is why the WHO is arranging a mega trial called SOLIDARITY to test 4 protocols.

- Remdesivir, an anti-Ebola drug, a RNA polymerase inhibitor
- Hydroxychloroquine - a drug used in SLE/Rheumatoid arthritis that may have some ACE2 blocking ability by glycosylating the spike protein and the ACE2 receptor
- Ritonavir and lopinavir, a combination of common anti-AIDS drugs
- Interferon beta + ritonavir and lopinavir- interferons are released by cells to fight viruses

https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/who-launch-trial-testing-4-potential-covid-19-treatments

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41421-020-0156-0

Comment: Thank you for your answer Graham Chiu.

Comment: What are some specific or particular medications for Covid-19 symptoms? For example, you also mentioned antivirals, like which one? or any kind? i.e. Is there no particular concern that a symptom came from Covid-19 infection ?

Comment: It's the same retrovirals in the other arm

Comment: What did you mean with your comment?

Comment: Arm 4 = arm 3 + interferon alpha

Comment: ah. Well, I should say that I am not a medical by no means so I don't get it; mind to be more clear in these advanced terms?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.genengnews.com/a-lists/how-to-conquer-coronavirus-top-35-treatments-in-development/ has a list of 35 treatments being considered / in development.

> A new survey by Genetic Engineering & Biotechnology News (GEN) reveals 35 active drug development programs in North America, Europe, and China. Those 35 include treatments that have received the greatest public attention in recent days, being developed by companies that range from pharma giants like GlaxoSmithKline and Sanofi, to small and large biotechs such as Moderna and Gilead Sciences. Gilead has begun clinical trials in China after peer-reviewed journals showed its antiviral candidate, remdesivir, having positive results in a case involving an American patient and Chinese in vitro tests.

Also, interesting summary of what supplements David Sinclair takes to reduce COVID-19 risk: https://podcastnotes.org/bulletproof-radio/david-sinclair-covid-19-supplements-immune-system/

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.

Comment: Do you know about my other question: "is a special medication to treat these symptoms that came particularly from Covid-19 infection?"

Comment: @America I'm not aware of any at the moment.